# Issue with Word2Vec embedding matrix

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

I am currenlty working on a ML project. I am stuck on the embedding matrix for my Word2Vec model.

The code snippet is below:;

```
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index)+1
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, embedding_vector_size))
# +1 is done because i starts from 1 instead of 0, and goes till len(vocab)
for  word, i in tokenizer.word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = model_1.wv[word] #error
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
```

The error I get is this message:

> raise KeyError(f"Key '{key}' not present") KeyError: "Key 'https' not present"

What would be a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is trying to find a word "https" in your word vector that doesn't exist. Try adding a check:

```
...
for  word, i in tokenizer.word_index.items():
  if word in model_1.wv:
    embedding_vector = model_1.wv[word] #error
...
```

You may want to do something if the word isn't found, so you can add an `else`.

Typically it's better to use the embedding methods than to manually search for a particular word, but I don't know your use case so this should catch the error.

Comment: ahhh such an easy fix, i'm facepalming.... thank you so much though!